# Clarity on using the include header.php line of code across all webpages

Tags: php

I am trying to use one header across all webpage, I found out that i have to use the include `header.php` which would save me the stress of writing the same code across all webpages. But i want to know three things 1) what line of code am I to cut? and 2) were do i cut it from, the `<nav bar>` or the entire `<menu div>`?  3) and where do i include the `header.php` line of code, at the part where i cut the code or at the top of the webpages?

```
<nav class="menu menu--horatio link-effect-8" id="link-effect-8">
                                <ul class="header_menu__list">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">Our Firm</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="biography.html">Lawyer Biographies</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="practise.html">Practise Area</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="consultation.html">Request A Consultation</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
```

This is the code i cut from the nav bar section to have a consistent header across all webpages. I just want to know where to use the `<php include header.php ?>`

Comment: `include()` essentially pastes a copy of the copy from the page you're including to the page you have the `include()` statement on. So if you were to have the above in `header.php`, you would get `<nav></nav>` copied to the page. That looks good to me, though it depends on exactly how your want to structure your pages for your specific use case.

Comment: Okay, i understood you answered two of my questions. Thank u @ObsidianAge Are you saying that i have to write the include `header.php` line of code back in the same <nav bar> section i cut out? Where exactly do i write it? And is it include `(header.php)` that I am to write?

Comment: header.php is a string. And strings in PHP are enclosed in quotes. therefore it's  `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` As of where, isn't it YOU to decide? Didn't you write it already in your question, " save me the stress of writing the same code across all webpages"? So shouldn't it go where that "same code across all webpages" currently is? I honestly don't understand your question. Basically it's "I want to replace a bunch of HTML with include. Where do I put it?" **Exactly in place of that bunch?**